# Use a ServiceManager-like system with extisting code

Tags: php, oop, factory

I work on a old-school framework with code like that: (*UserManager* is an exemple of multiple case like that)

```
// Somewhere ...
$user_manager = new UserManager();
[...]

// Somewhere else ...
$user_manager = new UserManager($context_variable);
[...]
```

We search to update the framework to be able to Override **UserManager** in projects who use this framework. In first think, we look about Zend Service Manager / Symfony Dependency Injector to make something like that:

```
// In the start, define services
$serviceManager = new ServiceManager();
// With configurable $user_manager_class in projects who use this framework.
$serviceManager->setService('user_manager', $user_manager_class); 

// And update code of framework when use this UserManager
// Somewhere ...
$user_manager = $serviceManager->get('user_manager');
```

But sometimes in framework **UserManager** is called with construct parameters:

```
// Somewhere ...
$user_manager = new UserManager($context_variable);
[...]
```

It seems not possible to use a Service Manager System for these cases ? As used in framework code UserManager is maybe not a *Service* ?
If we can just make a system to prepare the classname for future instanciations, what are clean way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$serviceManager->setService('user_manager', $user_manager_class);
```

when you set a service,you can allow passing constructor parameters,that can refer to other services.

```
$serviceManager->setService('user_manager', 
    $user_manager_class,array($constructorArg1,$constructorArg2));
```